# matching all the rows returned by a nested select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, relational-database, relational-algebra

I'm trying to find the name of the students who took ALL the courses a particular instructor offered (whose table is returned by the inner select statement.) However my query below returns the table of students who took ANY of those courses.

```
select distinct name
from takes natural join (select distinct  course_id
from instructor natural join teaches
where name like '%ck') as t natural join student
where dept_name='Biology'
```

I could post the whole schema of the database but really that would be an overshot. I'm probably missing a simple keyword in mysql. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please provide scheme of tables used  above

Comment: Here it is: http://i.imgur.com/oiP89EN.png

Comment: Dose student table contains course_I'd????

Comment: No, takes table does. That's why i natural joined them using ID.

Answer (score 1):

i have one solution dunno that is the best or not but it will work for the situation

```
    select name  
        from student
        where id in (select id from takes where  teacher like '%a')
    group by name
        having count(id) =
    (select count(id) from takes where teacher like '%a');
```

try this :) please make arrangements according to your schema

Comment: thanks for the effort but it's far off from what i need. i posted a closer one with only one problem that i shouldn't have known the student who took all the courses from the particular instructor was from Biology department.

Comment: @Umut  :( so it dose not worked out can you please lemme know where i missed so i can make it work..

Comment: first, it needs to be a single nested select statement very similar to the one i posted above. btw id and course_id are different things. instructor and student have id's, teaches and takes have course_id's as the schema shows.

Comment: the problem is last line (where dept_name='Biology') I wrote that because i knew the student who took all the courses from the particular instructor was from Biology department by manually inspecting the contents of the tables.

Comment: i need to know who took all the courses from that instructor regardless of students' department name.